# What use is the Aliases property of assembly references in Visual Studio 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, csproj

When I add an assembly reference to a project in Visual Studio 8 the Aliases property, of that reference, is set to "global".  What is this property good for and why is it set to global?

MSDN tells me that this is a list of aliases for the assembly but not why I might want to use this property or why most are aliased as "global".

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj80.reference3.aliases.aspx)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This is for "extern aliases". Suppose you want to use two different types, both of which are called `Foo.Bar` (i.e. `Bar` in a namespace of `Foo`). The two types will be in different assemblies (by definition) - you use the property in VS to associate an alias with each reference, then you can do:

```
extern alias FirstAlias;
extern alias SecondAlias;

using FirstBar = FirstAlias::Foo.Bar;
using SecondBar = SecondAlias::Foo.Bar;
```

and then use `FirstBar` and `SecondBar` in your code.

So basically it's an extra level of naming - and you shouldn't use it unless you really, really have to. It will confuse a lot of people. Try to avoid getting into that situation in the first place - but be aware of this solution for those times where you just can't avoid it.

Comment: I had the case, when a 3rd party vendor ship a product running on .Net V2, with a `System.Func<TResult>` delegate (maybe to replicate the V3.5 syntax?)... problems, of course, occurs when a .Net V4 project referenced the 3rd party library. Using alias, I avoided conflicts (Visual Studio has still some troubles and detect errors, but not the compiler). Using the extern keyword (first time I use today), I was able to explicitly target a type in the 3rd party library. I'm just a bit surprised to have to use the alias on a non-conflicting type.

Comment: `Infragistics4.Documents.Excel.v13.2` and `InfragisticsWPF4.Documents.Excel.v13.2` have this problem. In the process of merging two projects that will mixe Windows.Forms and WPF.

Comment: Has the Aliases property of a Reference gone away? I'm using VS 2017 Community and I can't find this option!

Comment: @PedroGaspar: Hmm - not sure. Will have to look tomorrow.

Answer (score 33):

Search for "[extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias)"; it is a very rarely used feature that is only needed to disambiguate between two dlls that contribute the same types (for example, two different versions of the same assembly, or two assemblies that have a class which shares a fully-qualified-name).

"global" is the default. For example, if you have a class called `Foo.System`, you can unambiguously refer to the main `System` namespace via `global::System`.

Comment: Working link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias