# .NET - Multiple libraries with the same namespace - referencing

Tags: c#, namespaces

Today I am faced with a curious challenge...

This challenge involves two .NET libraries that I need to reference from my application. Both of which I have no control over and have the same namespace within them.

So...

I have `foo.dll` that contains a `Widget` class that is located on the `Blue.Red.Orange` namespace.

I have `bar.dll` that also contains a `Widget` class that is also located on the `Blue.Red.Orange` namespace.

Finally I have my application that needs to reference both `foo.dll` and `bar.dll`.  This is needed as within my application I need to use the `Widget` class from `foo` and also the `Widget` class from `bar`

So, the question is how can I manage these references so that I can be certain I am using the correct `Widget` class?

As mentioned, I have no control over the `foo` or `bar` libraries, they are what they are and cannot be changed.  I do however have full control over my application.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to use an [*extern alias*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) - introduced in C# 2.

Anson Horton has a [walkthrough on his blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110220152008/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) which you may find useful.

Comment: Might be worth noting, every assembly has the extern alias of `global` by default

Comment: Aliases seems to be an option for different versions of the same assembly, not for different assembly purposes, that´s just wrong architecture.

Comment: @Augusto: It works either for different versions of the same assembly, or for different assemblies which include the same namespace-qualified type name. It's not solely for one situation or the other. Are you claiming my solution wouldn't work? If so, do you have anything to back up that claim?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Your solution isn't the problem, but it's a clever "hack" for an architecture problem. He shouldn't have two different classes with same name within same namespaces in different assemblies. For two different implementations of the same concept he should be using an interface. As he doesn't have control over it, I suppose your solution is fine.

Comment: @Augusto: Don't forget that the libraries may be third party ones, with no individual third party doing anything wrong (although the common case here would probably be inappropriate use of the "global" namespace).

Comment: How can I use extern in my Razor or webform views?

Comment: @user960567: No idea, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet walkthrough link is dead

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to use `extern alias`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx

Here's a walkthrough. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "**Aliases**" property for resolving conflicts. Select the library and open Property window. This is already discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8.)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thats tricky. I tink, I would create two wrapper-DLLs:

1. MyBarWrapper.dll (which has a reference to bar.dll)
2. MyFooWrapper.dll (which has a reference to foo.dll)

and support different namespaces there.

Comment: Sorry. I did not recognize the extern alias. Would be a better approach I think.

Answer (score -1):

I'd be surprised if you can do this, without using reflection.

It might be easier to create your own FooWrapper and BarWrapper dlls which reference foo and bar and expose their contents again under different namespaces.

Comment: Consider yourself surprised :)