# 'You must add a reference to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common' even though assembly is in the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, reference

I'm trying to compile an application for which I have the solution and can't get past:

> 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.IConfigurationSource'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

So I added the assembly to the GAC:

[image]

After some research I opened up visual studio with the [Fusion Assembly Binding Viewer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) running, which seemed to create a lot of logs but none that related to this exact version of the assembly (however 4.1.0.0 *is* in there).

I can't simply add -> reference as VS tells me that a reference with the same name already exists.

What other avenues should I explore?

Comment: Why don't you use EntLib 5.0?

Comment: This isn't my project, I just need to be able to compile it

Comment: If there is an existing reference then try removing the existing reference and then re-adding it.  Having the assembly in the GAC will make no difference at compile time.

Comment: There is an existing reference for `4.1.0.0`, if I remove that and add `3.1.0.0` I get the missing assembly message for `4.1.0.0`

Comment: @Justin - If adding to the GAC won't make any difference at compile time how can I force it to take the assembly from there?

Comment: @m.edmondson If you wish to reference two versions of the same assembly then you need to use an extern alias.  See [.NET - Multiple libraries with the same namespace - referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759726/net-multiple-libraries-with-the-same-namespace-referencing)

Comment: @Justin - But since I've been given this project as working I shouldn't need to modify the code

Comment: Was the existing reference looking to the GAC? If it's looking to something like `C:\users\Alice\projects\someproject\lib` then that's going to fail. Remove it, then add a reference to whatever version that removed reference had been to.

Comment: @Jon - The reference was pointing to a directory - but if I remove then I get compile errors and if I put it back it's just the same as before

Comment: As a side note the assemblies do not appear in the .net tab but I'm forced to reference on disk

Comment: Compile errors when you remove it and put in a new reference to where the same version of the assembly is on your own system?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to Alias the assembly also if you are using .net 4.0 you would have to have an entry in the .config file for example that shows the old assembly name referencing the new assembly name. Several other things to keep in mind .. if the .DLL is in the GAC and you don't have a copy of that assembly in the bin folder, this could cause an issue..

Is this local referencing or is the code on a remote machine ..? if it's a remote machine.. why not add that specific assembly to the GAC.. notice the versioning difference of the two assembly's in your screen shot as well..