# Ambiguous class Reference when using Linked File in Different Projects in Razor?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 5 to 6 projects. Project A and B use a same file via Linked File. Now, if I use this class in Razor I will get,

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
```

*Because Razor views reference all the dlls in bin*. It is referencing the same class from Project A and B. How to tell the Razor during compilation use Project A and not Project B?

Comment: Why don't you use signatures? At least don't use linked files and separate them to avoid overlapping! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use Linked Files when including the assembly too. Why do you need the referenced class twice? There is no point in that.

You have to put that file in a separate project and reference that one in A, B and your MVC project. This makes you don't need the linked files any more.

Another way is to get the assembly and from this assembly, get the type using reflection and then call the method.

Comment: What makes Razor different then every other .NET project?

Comment: When compiling Razor views, it will reference all the dlls in bin folder.

Comment: Still, you include a reference and a class in linked file. That will never work.

Comment: @user960567 Patrick Hofman is right, create a project and put a class to communicate with this linked file and let the project a and b to reference this new project c, this way you will get rid from the problem

Comment: @user960567: Need more help?

Comment: I need to apply C# extern in Razor how can we do this?

Comment: Why would you need that? You mean [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx), right? You should incorporate that in the controller, not in the view.

Comment: I think from reflection I can grab the assembly and then type and invoke the action method.

Comment: Why would you? Just make a simple assembly containing this logic and include that in all others. Then you don't need linked files, and the problem is gone.

Comment: Come on patrick. This is not test project and sample project. This is a big production app. It is not easy for us remove all common code and move it in a new assembly.

Comment: @user960567: I understand your problem. It is what you should do though. In my years I have had to do this multiple times. It costs some time, but it is necessary sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kind a tricky answer but **you can add another class in one of your two projects and this class will just inherit from your shared class**.

Then you can use this new class in the Razor without any problems

Answer (score -1):

You should use the full namespace

```
Solution.ProjectA.MyClass
```

Answer (score -1):

ASP.NET Razor Views allow you to use using statements just like you would in a normal cs class. You just need to add the @ symbol

```
@using MyNamespace.ProjectA
```

It will work the same as a cs class.

Comment: I am talking about same class with same namespace. In short I need extern alias http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759726/net-multiple-libraries-with-the-same-namespace-referencing