# how to resolve Duplicate namspaces in c#

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I have 2 assemblies `Combres` and `log4net`

Both assemblies contain the same `log4net.Appender` namespace (internal code included) - I need to inherit `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender`.

How do I accomplish this.

Comment: `using log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender;` doesn't get the right one for you?

Comment: @Marco: `AdoNetAppender` is a class.

Comment: You answered your question by inheriting log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.

Comment: no it doesnt know which one to use cos the namespace is duplicated

Comment: I'm quite sure that Combres does __not__ use the `log4net.Appender` namespace but `Combres.Loggers` namespace.... Maybe the root cause of the error is elsewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fully qualify the type.  For example if you are trying to inherit from this class:

```
class MyAppender : log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender
```

If you are trying to use / create an instance of this class:

```
var appender = log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender;
```

If `Combres` and `log4net` both contain a type `AdoNetAppender` in the `log4net.Appender` namespace then you are in more trouble (and someone made a mistake - namespaces are designed to avoid these sorts of conflicts).

If this does happen then you can use the assembly reference "Aliases" property to resolve the conflict as described in [What use is the Aliases property of assembly references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8).

Comment: awsome answer totally HG (Higher Grade)

Answer (score 7):

You can probably specify an alias for one of the namespaces, like this:

```
using MyNameSpace = log4net.Appender;
```

Then inherit MyNameSpace.AdoNetAppender

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation for [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). It allows you to explicitly reference classes in your code even if they are in the same namespace and have the same name.

You might, for example, reference the log4net classes like so:

```
extern alias l4n;

//... further down

l4n::log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender l4nAppender = null;
```

The "l4n" alias also has to be added to the property page for the DLL reference in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that Combres itself does not use the `log4net.Appender` namespace but `Combres.Loggers` namespace.

But `Combres` (2.2.1) contains a reference to `log4net`. If your application contains a reference to `log4net` as well (possibly even in another location than the log4net assembly that is referenced by Combres), this could result in the error you described.

(*Multiple log4net-assemblies are referenced* and of course these all contain the  `log4net.Appender`)