# dll binding for asp.net (dll versioning)

Tags: asp.net, dll, web-config, versioning, assemblybinding

I know this is a very basic question - but I did not face this issue till now - so am asking for help.

I have two dll files, with the same name (example.dll), but fortunately with diff version numbers 1.0.3180.20767 and 1.0.2490.20011. I want to use both these dll in the same project.

How do I use them? - Simply clicking "Add reference" fails with the following message[image]

I can rename the files so that they are now called "example1.dll" and "example2.dll" - but is that ok? is there a better way to do this.

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that after adding the first assembly, go to properties of that reference and assign an alias to it. Then it should be possible to add the second one as well.

Comment: I followed your advice with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8, and I got the solution that worked for me.


Thanks!!