# Is it possible to remove, or combat conflicts from the .NET user class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my .NET MVC project I have a model called User, whoose class is conflicting with System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.WebPageRenderingBase.User when I'm inside a razor view. (and only inside a razor view).

Is there a way to give my class a different global alias? or better yet, stop this .NET class from showing up?

I don't want a verbose solution. (prefixing) is there a way to remvoe reference to this stupid User property?

Is this a common problem for everyone or is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: See the very first comment to the answer below. That has your answer.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'd like to look at a better solution, that alias works well, but you have to do it in every razor view.

Comment: The best solution, IMHO, is to rename your class.

Answer (score 12):

Just rename your model class from `User` to `Person`.  Every solution will bloat your code with unnecesary complexity.

Other thing:
If you are using a class named `User` 99% certain that you are using your models in views, where the best approach is using a ViewModel, where you collect all the data you need to pass to your view.  So, in a view, the User would became one property of this ViewModel.

This approach also help you in eradicate the use of ViewBags and similar...

Comment: Ah I'm using Viewmodels in views thanks tho! :-) I just don't create a Viewmodel for a view if it doesn't need it.

Comment: Thank you also for the person recommendaion! I may look at doing this, of course it means I'd have to change the routes from person -> user which is a bit annoying. Hmph!!, why on earth is there a property called User exposed in razor views, seems silly to me!

Comment: I've got to agree with renaming your model. If you can avoid name clashes with parts of the .net framework, then do it.  If it's really not possible to rename, then take a look at the answer further down about fully qualifying the class - it's not pretty, but it will work

Answer (score 4):

Fully qualify your class i.e.

```
MyNamespace.Core.User
```

as opposed to just

```
User
```

Although I'm a little confused because

```
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal.WebPageRenderingBase.User
```

Is a property of type `IPrincipal` not a type called `User`

Comment: Also, if you need a particular class in just one file, you can use this at the top:  `using ClassName = Fully.Qualified.Namespace.ClassName;` and it will assume for the duration of that file that unqualified references to `ClassName` are for the class you specified.

Comment: :O that's super neat! I had no idea!

Comment: Perhaps it's a conflict with the `User` property for code that executes in a class derived from `WebPageRenderingBase`

Comment: I thought that as well, but I'm fairly sure I can declare a `User u = new User();` inside a class with a `this.User` property without any compilation errors. You'll probably get yelled at if you try to call a static method on the similarly named class though.

Comment: I'd like a global solution if possible, and one without a verbose namespace prefixing everytime. sigh annoying huh!

Answer (score 4):

I typically do something like the following:

```
using m = MyProject.MyNameSpace.MySubNameSpace;

var u = new m.User();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat of a mix between @devlife and @Romias answers.

By implementing a `using` alias you can "rename" (in the file this is defined in) your `User` class to something you specify in the `using` statements.

For example:

```
using Person = NameSpace.SubNameSpace.Classes.User
```

Then you can use `Person` as your `User` class within the file that this alias is defined in.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.71).aspx

The last section provides a full code example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the great Jon Skeet has your answer:

"[What use is the Aliases property of assembly references in Visual Studio 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/)":

> This is for "extern aliases". Suppose you want to use two different
>   types, both of which are called Foo.Bar (i.e. Bar in a namespace of
>   Foo). The two types will be in different assemblies (by definition) -
>   you use the property in VS to associate an alias with each reference,
>   then you can do:
>
> ```
> extern alias FirstAlias;
> extern alias SecondAlias;
>
> using FirstBar = FirstAlias::Foo.Bar;
> using SecondBar = SecondAlias::Foo.Bar;
> ```
>
> and then use FirstBar and SecondBar in your code.
>
> So basically it's an extra level of naming - and you shouldn't use it
>   unless you really, really have to. It will confuse a lot of people.
>   Try to avoid getting into that situation in the first place - but be
>   aware of this solution for those times where you just can't avoid it.

Comment: This user does not have that problem. They have a class named 'User' conflicting with a *member* named user, not another class.

Comment: Hrm I guess. Never used Razor Views, but I would've figured this is exactly what he was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Had nothing to do with Razor; what you posted is for dealing with the classes of the same name and namespace. That's not the OP's problem at all.