# Does a Visual Studio 2012 project use a reference DLL or local file first?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I may not be asking this question correctly as I haven't been able to find a reference here or on Google. I need to modify a class that is in one of my reference DLL's. Will VS look at the reference DLL first or the local file first ?  It seems to look at the reference DLL first. Is there a way to tell VS which to look at first ?

Thanks

Clarification - I have a class definition in the reference DLL and also in a local project file. The local project file is the class definition that I need the program to use.

Comment: Is the class a part of the solution? How have you referenced the class in your solution?

Comment: Yes, the class is a part of the solution. The class that I need to change, locally, is called from another class definition (also in the DLL reference). I do not instantiate the class directly.

Comment: I don't understand your question quite well:
 - what is the local file?
 - is the class you are refering too defined in both, the DLL and your local file?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in both places. I need it to look at the local class definition first.

Comment: You might want to edit/extend your question further... Best would be if you could provide sample code... This might help in providing better answers.

Comment: Sample code may not help in this particular case. It would be easier to open the project file in a text editor like Notepad++ and look at the references. This has been a very helpful tool in my arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

Using an alias on your references, you can specify which of two similarly named classes you are referring to in your code.

This is explained by Jon Skeet here:
[What use is the Aliases property of assembly references in Visual Studio 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8)

**Limitations**

This will only help you, if you instanciate that class yourself. It is not possible to let a foreign assembly create instances of your own class if there is no dedicated mechanism (i.e. API) for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but if you use the Fusion Log Viewer `FusLogVw.exe` (just search for it on your computer) you can see what dlls are loaded and which paths were used to look for it.

Comment: Thanks. Basically, if a Person Class definition exists in a DLL reference and also in a local file, which will VS look at first ? I need it to look at the local definition.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you setup your reference to the project in question.  Visual Studio has 2 concepts of references.

1. Project to Project
2. Project to DLL

For the sake of this discussion lets call the main project A and the referenced project B (the class to change is located in B)

If there is a project to project reference from A to B then the build is always against the latest source code.  Hence if you change the class definition A will always build against the changed class.

If there is a project to DLL reference from A to B then things are a bit murkier.  There are so many possibilities here that it is hard to speculate intelligently what will happen.  It may get the updated class, it may not, it may after a second rebuild.

In general though if you have 2 projects in the same solution and one references the other you should always use a project to project reference.  The easiest way to guarantee this is to delete the reference, right click select add reference and go through the project route instead of "Browse".