# How can I use two different versions of a DLL in my software?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I am running into a conflict with 2 packages I am using. One is using 1.4.7.0 version of HtmlAgilityPack.dll while the other is using 1.4.9.0

This causes the software to become non-functional as each package relies on certain things in their respective .dll version. How can I use both versions and make sure everything works together nicely? Everyone always insists on providing code but I am not sure what I would need to supply in this instance. I am using Visual Studio 2015 if that helps.

Comment: Did you try to upgrade you app to use the latest version of the library? What is the blocking code that stops you to do such a logical action?

Comment: They are both the latest version. The issue lies with one package using the Universal app version of htmlagility which dosn't support XPath. The other package uses the normal version. The two don't seem like they will ever work properly together. So I need to figure out a way to differentiate the two dlls.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8 (although I'm not aware of the same syntax for VB it may get you started)

Comment: Thank you the conversion to vb.net is no problem this is a good start.

Comment: I ended up de-compiling one htmlagilitypack version and changing the namespace. Then decompiling one of the packages and have it use this new .dll. Horrible hair pulling time. DLL Hell.