# JsonConvert Exists in both Newtonsoft and System.Net.Http.Formatting Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: json, macos, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a project I have been working on using Xamarin's MonoDevelop.

I have been using Newtonsoft's Json nuget package.

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2017 for Mac.

I try to build my project in VS2017Mac and get the following error:

```
error CS0433: The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I thought I should be able to fix that by just adding Newtonsoft.Json. to the front of JsonConvert, but that didn't work.

I don't want to remove Newtonsoft's implementation if possible because I think their library still has more functionality. Is there another way to resolve this? Why didn't adding the full assembly reference work?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing for the `JsonIgnore` attribute as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In the Properties window for the project's Newtonsoft.Json reference, change the value of Aliases from `global` to `global, foo`.
2. Insert `extern alias foo;` as the first line of any class that consumes Newtonsoft.Json.
3. Qualify members with `foo.`. Example: `foo.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)}`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the following error message but with another library(Ranet) in C#:

> Error CS0433 The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Json, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' and
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

I solved it using aliases, but I would like to provide a bit more detail as I struggled to implement using the instructions from these answers and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/286645/2912011). This is how I did it:

1. In the solution explorer, right click on the "Newtonsoft.json", add ", Newton" to the alias field, it should look something like this:

[image]

2. Add the following code to the first line of you file(before all using statements):

```cs
extern alias Newton;
```

3. Add the following reference to the end of your using statements:

```cs
using NewtonReference = Newton::Newtonsoft.Json;
```

4. Now you can call Newtonsoft method using the following code:

```cs
NewtonReference.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("");
```

5. A final example would look something like this:

```cs
extern alias Newton;

using System;
using NewtonReference = Newton::Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Test {     
    public static List<string> TestMethod() {
        NewtonReference.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("");  
    }  
}
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution, I went to the project references and it showed two different versions of Newtonsoft (versions 12.0.0 and 6.0.0 for me). I clicked on the older version and it showed me the file path to where it was stored. I simply went there and deleted it. Once that was done I had the same problem with version 9.0.0 and did the same thing. When I opened it up again the problem was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

install previous ver of newtonsoft.json package.