# Ignoring a conflicting definition from global namespace in a single C# file

Tags: c#

I have a generated code file that creates a class and doesn't give it a namespace. Because the code is generated and updated some times I don't want to add any additional code there.

```
using System;

public class Apartment { ... }
```

I also have the Apartment class in a namespace (in different dll).

```
using System;
namespace My.Core.Entities {
  public class Apartment  { ... }
}
```

Now, I try to use the former one in a unit test (that references to both dlls). I have tried following code to ignore the global class.

```
using System;
using Apartment = Core.Entities.Apartment;
using GlobApartment = global::Apartment

public class Tests {
  private List<Apartment> _apartments = new List<Apartment>();
}
```

It gives the error `Namespace '<global namespace>' contains a definition conflicting with alias 'Apartment'`

I understand why the error happens. The question is if there is any way to ignore the global::Apartment some way in this file (I tried the `using GlobApartment` thing)? I wouldn't like to change all Apartment to My.Core.Entities.Apartment. Is there any way to use the single term `Apartment` in the code?

Comment: Did you try the other way round? Leaving the global Apartment alone and aliasing My.Core.Entities.Apartment to eg "MyApartment" ?

Comment: It's too many `Apartment` words. Give alias a better name, e.g. `EntityAppartment`.

Comment: @Fildor and Sinatr, yes, that is one way to go around this. Maybe this question is, at this point, if there is some technical thing in C# with what you could ignore some global class name.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried using [static using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) statements, doesn't work - the one in global namespace gets preference. I have also tried giving the global type an alias (as shown in the OP) - does not work. The only solution that works is giving the non-global one an alias (as pointed out by [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802654/ignoring-a-conflicting-definition-from-global-namespace-in-a-single-c-sharp-file#comment100159844_56802654))

```
using ApartmentEntity = Core.Entities.Apartment;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "ignore" just one class, but you can isolate all types from a referenced assembly in a separate top-level namespace and import only what you need into your namespace(s). Give the assembly with the generated `Apartment` class an [extern alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8). Then you'll be able to say

```
extern alias generated ;
using GeneratedApartment = generated::Apartment ;
// or just use generated::Apartment in your code
```

The generated `Apartment` will no longer be present in the `global::` root namespace and you won't have conflicts.

Comment: But will the codes that depend on the generated class `Apartment` to be in global namespace work? I guess not.

Comment: What "codes"? OP is writing unit tests, and considered renaming the generated class to `GlobApartment`, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: By "codes" I meant codes that use this generated class considering it to be present in the global namespace (and I do not want to make any change to such codes, heck, I don't even know the "codes" with such dependency in my solution). BTW, the OP considered aliasing the generated global `Apartment` to `GlobApartment` only in the file that they are writing/changing, but using `extern alias` will cause the generated `Apartment` to be _no longer present in the `global::` root namespace_ as you said.