# How to resolve a namespace collision between two packages

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

In our C# project we need two external packages. Both packages declare a class with the same name and in the same namespace.
Obviously bad practice of the package builders, but now it is our problem.

Note: there are to seperate packages, it's not just a package version problem

I found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias), but it does not explain wat to place where to make it work.

Is there a way to reference a class not only by its namespace but also by its package / assembly name?

Comment: *"Both packages declare a class with the same name and in the same namespace."* - are they the same package with different version?

Comment: Use [Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/286645/7450780).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What use is the Aliases property of assembly references in Visual Studio 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286632/what-use-is-the-aliases-property-of-assembly-references-in-visual-studio-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your project file as below DataHelpers class in namespace SqlServerLibrary can be accessed with SLD.

```xml
<!-- specifies the class project which the next two groups define aliases for -->
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\SqlServerLibrary\SqlServerLibrary.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- alias for the class DataHelpers SLD is the combination for each uppercased letter in the path -->
<ItemGroup>
   <Using Include="SqlServerLibrary.DataHelpers" Alias="SLD" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Accessing a method in DataHelpers

```cs
WriteLine(SLD.ExpressDatabaseExists("NorthWind2022") ? "Exists" : "Not found");
```

If using this with a team of developers, make sure to educate them about aliasing.